# Rails 3 and apple push notification service

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apple-push-notifications

Has anybody been able to send push notification to iPhone using rails 3 ?
[APN on rails](http://apnonrails.metabates.com/) and [samesoffes plugin](https://github.com/samsoffes/apple_push_notification) only works with rails 2. I am new to rails and i have not been able to make either of them work.

Here are the errors i encountered :

APN on Rails :

tried to replace

```
ruby script/generate apn_migrations
```

With

```
rails generate apn_migrations
```

got :

> myApp/config/environment.rb:5:in
>   `require': no such file to load --
>   apn_on_rails (LoadError)

I also did not manage to run the configuration "config.gem 'apn_on_rails'" (config.gem: command not found)

Samsoffes plugin :

I did not manage to config the gem :

```
config.gem "apple_push_notification", :source => "http://gemcutter.org/"
```

gave me :

> http://gemcutter.org/: No such file or
>   directory

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks,
Vincent

Comment: Sorry Vincent. I haven't worked on that gem in years. Others recommended here look like good alternatives.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem, I had used a rails3 branch

gem 'apn_on_rails', :git => 'https://github.com/natescherer/apn_on_rails.git', :branch => 'rails3'

This solved my problem and I wrote the details to my blog

http://yekmer.posterous.com/how-to-send-iphone-push-notifications-in-rail

Comment: Great tutorial! but I am getting the error uninitialized constant APN::Device . I have added require 'apn_on_rails' on my environment.rb   Do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: It seems that you could not load APN library correctly, I have no idea why you could not load it

Comment: Unfortunately your blog isn't online anymore. Have you published your solution also somewhere else?

Comment: Posterous has been closed, I will move my blog but I recommend you look for another solution, it is a rather old post, I am sure there are lots of new libraries.

Answer (score 14):

I've written an apn_on_rails replacement called Rpush specifically targeted at Rails 3. I've also added a bunch of extra features like persistent connections to the APNs (as recommended by Apple). Frequent connects/disconnects may get you banned from the APNs, which is how apn_on_rails currently works.

Rpush: https://github.com/rpush/rpush

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use your rapns gem on heroku but got some error, can you please help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521207/using-rapns-on-heroku-for-push-notification

Answer (score 0):

In rails 3, there is no config.gem... Open up your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'apple_push_notification', :git => 'http://gemcutter.org/path_to_that_gem_on_gem_cutter.git'
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i still get an error when using "bundle install": bundle install
Fetching http://rubygems.org/gems/apple_push_notification
fatal: http://rubygems.org/gems/apple_push_notification/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
An error has occurred in git when running `git clone "http://rubygems.org/gems/apple_push_notification" "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/cache/bundler/git/apple_push_notification-fc1fb9f2476b5302441ccfbe6e128df192ffe790" --bare --no-hardlinks`. Cannot complete bundling.