# Configatron error with the rails3 branch of the apn-on-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, apple-push-notifications

I am receiving this error when I try to deliver pending push notifications (both via the rake task and the object call):

```
rake aborted!
can't convert Configatron::Store to String (Configatron::Store#to_str gives Configatron::Store)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am using the rails3 branch of [apn_on_rails](https://github.com/natescherer/apn_on_rails), specified in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633112/rails-3-and-apple-push-notification-service) SO question, with ruby 1.9.2 and rvm.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'apn_on_rails', :git => 'https://github.com/natescherer/apn_on_rails.git', :branch => 'rails3'
gem 'configatron'
```

and my config\environments\development.rb:

```
  # development (delivery):
  configatron.apn.passphrase # => '1234'
  configatron.apn.port # => 2195
  configatron.apn.host # => 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com'
  configatron.apn.cert #=> File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'config', 'apple_push_notification_development.pem')
```

Any ideas?  (disclaimer: I am somewhat of a rails newbie.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign a value to a configuration parameter you have to use the = operator.
For example, configatron.apn.passphrase = '1234'.

In ruby # marks the start of a comment.

Comment: ha! Thanks.  Biggest ruby rookie move e v e r.

Comment: @matteo: even after assigning value, i am getting the value in my development console but values are not available in other gem (apn_on_rails gem) code. values are being returned as ({}) empty hash. any idea, about how to access configatron values in other gem code?

Answer (score 1):

I've been look at this issue myself as I'm using apn_on_rails and have noticed that it's recently started breaking with the same error with Configatron.

I noticed that it started happening after I updated my bundle and, specifically, Configatron up to 3.x. I downgraded to 2.13.0 and it now works without an error - I guess apn_on_rails doesn't play nice with Configatron v3.x.

Suggest in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'configatron', '2.13.0'
```

and then run

```
bundle update configatron
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this error happened to me just using "plain" configatron (i'm not using apn_on...) reverting the gem to 2.13.0 made it work

Comment: just in case someone wastes 5 minutes by copy and pasting your line, there is a typo it's "gem 'configatron', '2.13.0'" and not "configratron" :)