# Is there a simple way to tell if a Gem will work in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I wanted to use this gem:

https://github.com/PRX/apn_on_rails

Finally, after digging through the issues, seems it's not Rails3 ready (yet).  Is there some simple way of finding is something is Rails 3 compatible without digging all over?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from creating a fresh Rails app and giving it a try, I tend to look at the commit messages of forks created by other users (i.e. https://github.com/PRX/apn_on_rails/network). In this instance, it looks like there is [a fork](https://github.com/timsu/apn_on_rails) that runs on Rails 3 that is still being maintained.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I thought there may have been some gemfile type voodoo that I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if it isn't mentioned in the readme (on github) then no.  Most gems I have used explicitly specify rails 2 and rails 3 install instructions.  If this is not the case, then usually someone else will have asked this question and a quick search will reveal.

One other giveaway is the install instructions.  The rails 2 way of installing a gem via a Gemfile is:

```
config.gem GEMNAME
```

The rails 3 way is:

```
gem 'apn_on_rails'
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633112/rails-3-and-apple-push-notification-service) answer is related to the gem you are looking for.